# How can I sort data by created month

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to sort data in my database by created month. And show data in my template created only certain month. But the error says that 'datetime.date' is not iterable. Any idea how can I sort data by month?

Here is my model:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Report(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    month = models.DateField(default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.area)

    def months(self):
        return self.month
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def report_list_by_month(request):    
    report = Report.objects.all().distinct('month')
    context = {

        'report': report
    }
    return render(request, 'report/report_list_by_month.html', context)
```

Here is my report_list_by_month.html and screenshot:

```
    {% for month in report %}
      <a href="{% url 'users:report-list-sorted-by-month' month.pk %}">{{month.month|date:"F"}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

[image: Here is my report_list_by_month.html screen shot:]

```
def sorted_by_month(request, pk):
    months = Report()
    months_query = months.month

    context = {
        'month': months_query    
    }
    return render(request, 'report/report_list.html', context)
```

Here is my report_list.html code and error screenshot:

```
{% for month in month %}
{{month}}
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `sorted_by_month()` you are creating a `Report()` instance, and assigning `months_query` to the `month` field of that instance.  This then gets set in your context, and you attempt to iterate in the template.

Therefore you are trying to iterate over the month field of a Report instance, which is not iterable.

It should be easy to solve.  `month_query` should be set to something like:

```py
months_query = Report.objects.all().distinct('month').order_by('month')
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, how to get all the posts created in May?

Comment: To [filter by month](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month): `Report.objects.filter(month__month=5)`